# Why does my image from the android gallery not scale down?

Tags: android, image, resize

I want to scale down an image so that it fits the size of my image button. In this code I open up the gallery and then can pick an image. The problem is that the image does not scale down although I said so in my code. 
Why does this not work?

```
private static final int NEW_WIDTH = 10;
private static final int NEW_HEIGHT = 10;

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourSelectedImage, NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, false);
            mImageButton.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using ImageButton.setScaleType(int) (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem by myself.

Instead of:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourSelectedImage, NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, false);
mImageButton.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
```

Type in:

```
Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourSelectedImage, NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, true);
mImageButton.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
```

I found this article very helpful:
http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/3/